# TL-WR1043ND v.1 (1.8) WAN to LAN port

Tags: networking, router

TL-WR1043ND v.1 (1.8),Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (08/07/10) std with fried WAN port, I need to reassign the WAN port to one of the LAN ports, and also to change the new WAN port ( let's say LAN port 4 ) Mac addr because the ISP is stopping connection on IP/MAC. Simply adding the port using Vlan.asp and Mac Clone does not work. Can someone with more experience help me with telnet script / commands or other method. As far as I know dd-wrt should be able to do that, if you know how to do it with Open-wrt please provide instruction for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, consumer-grade routers usually have only two router ports: WAN and LAN (the LAN port is internal and connects to the switch module, where the ports are switch ports, not router ports). The ports are fixed, and you cannot change a switch port into a router port.

Comment: @RonMaupin Depends on the router. Some have all ports on a single switch, and "WAN" is simply on a different VLAN than "LAN". I think this is such a router. In any case, "WAN" is quite fluid on third party firmware and can be moved anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It can be done with newer version DD-WRT. The telnet commands are :

> swconfig dev rtl8366rb vlan 1 set ports "0 1 2 3 5t"
>
> swconfig dev rtl8366rb vlan 2 set ports "4 5t"

to set LAN port 4 as WAN port. This is for 1043ND for other Atheros based router do :

> swconfig dev list

- to get the switch and change accordingly